# Change range of particle system start colours in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hopefully a simple question. I want to change the two start colors for the 'random between two colors' start colors in the particle system component, using C# in unity, however, can't seem to figure out how.

Here is the code I thought would do it, but it does not:

```
void Start () {
     Color particleMax = gameObject.GetComponent<ParticleSystem> ().main.startColor.colorMax;
     particleMax = Color.red;
     Color particleMin = gameObject.GetComponent<ParticleSystem> ().main.startColor.colorMin;
     particleMin = Color.white;
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Color in Unity3D is a value type (struct) not a reference type. If you want to set the gradient try this instead:

```
void Start () {
    ParticleSystem.MainModule psMain = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().main;
    psMain.startColor = new ParticleSystem.MinMaxGradient(Color.white, Color.red);
}
```

Comment: Tried this already, give an error saying 'cannot modify a value type return value of 'unityengine.particlesystem.mainmodule.startcolor' consider storing the value in a temporary variable. Which is what I was trying above ^. Thanks

Comment: Sorry @Mattattack, I have tested the code and changed my answer. It should work now.